# Where to find a chart of Monero per Bitcoin exchange rate

Tags: exchange, bitcoin

I have searched around but all there seems to be are time series charts of XMR / BTC which at the moment is 0.006.

I don't want to look at numbers like 0.006, would rather be looking at the inverse, which happens to be 166.

Anyone know where to find such a chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first result I just found in a web search: https://exchangerate.guru/btc/xmr/1/ (which includes the chart flipped as requested).

I'm sure there are others too.

Comment: 1 BTC
=
229.58 XMR / Source: https://btc.currencyrate.today/xmr